# C++: Creating a variable length tuple based on integral template parameter

Tags: c++, c++14, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I am writing a library that has compile time polymorphic objects templated on unsigned integers,

```
template<unsigned level> class Foo { ... };
```

, i.e. Foo<0>, Foo<1>, Foo<2> etc up to a certain number determined by each application . Let's say our application specifies the need for numbers 0, 1,..., n.

I need to be able to construct a tuple of vectors of pointers to these objects: `std::tuple<std::vector<Foo<n> *>, std::vector<Foo<n-1> *>, ..., vector<Foo<0> *>>` by invoking a variadic template function, schematically:

```
template <unsigned n> 
std::tuple<unsigned n, unsigned... Args> create_vector_tuple<n>()
```

or something like it.

My intuition tells me that this should be possible to accomplish though I am way out of my depth here.

I would be very grateful if anyone could point me to a way to implement this!

Comment: I've never had a need for it myself, but maybe you want to use [std::integer_sequence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like the following:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

template<unsigned level> struct Foo {};

template<unsigned N, unsigned... Ns>
std::tuple<std::vector<Foo<N - Ns>*>...> create_vector_tuple_imp(std::integer_sequence<unsigned, Ns...>) {
    return {};
}

template <unsigned n>
auto create_vector_tuple() {
    return create_vector_tuple_imp<n>(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, n>{});
}

template<class T>
void print() {
    std::printf("%s\n", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

int main() {
    auto t = create_vector_tuple<10>();
    print<decltype(t)>();
}
```

Outputs:

```
void print() [with T = std::tuple<std::vector<Foo<10u>*, std::allocator<Foo<10u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<9u>*, std::allocator<Foo<9u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<8u>*, std::allocator<Foo<8u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<7u>*, std::allocator<Foo<7u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<6u>*, std::allocator<Foo<6u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<5u>*, std::allocator<Foo<5u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<4u>*, std::allocator<Foo<4u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<3u>*, std::allocator<Foo<3u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<2u>*, std::allocator<Foo<2u>*> >, std::vector<Foo<1u>*, std::allocator<Foo<1u>*> > >]
```

Comment: Note that this requires C++14 support for `std::make_integer_sequence` and `auto` without the trailing return type. `std::make_integer_sequence` can be backported to C++11, and change the declaration to `auto create_vector_tuple() -> decltype(create_vector_tuple_imp<n>(std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, n>{}))` to add the trailing return type if necessary.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Haven't tested your suggestion yet, but spontaneously it looks like exactly what I was looking for. I'm writing in C++14, so that's no problem (chose tag C++11 as a wider umbrella than C++14).

Comment: Nice but... are you sure about `std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, n>`? Or should be `std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, n+1U>`?

Comment: @max66 You are right, if `Foo<0>` is needed in there, then it should be `std::make_integer_sequence<unsigned, n + 1>{}`.